# How to develop Sharepoint Webpart using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am trying to develop a WebPart for Sharepoint 2007, currently i am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, but the oldest version is sharepoint 2010.
I have tried to find 2007 templates under Tools-> Extensions and Updates  but i am unable.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint 2007 is not supported in Visual Studio 2013 , but is you manually update the project to Sharepoint 2010 tehn it may open that up..
See the link as given below :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx